# How can I get the body of an HttpUriRequest object

Tags: http, httprequest

can anyone show me a simple way to get the entity body of an httpurirequest object.

Br

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HttpUriRequest](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest.html) is the base interface for all HTTP requests, including those which don't have a body.

Requests with a body implement the [HttpEntityEnclosingRequest](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html?is-external=true) interface, which provides a [getEntity()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html#getEntity()) method.